# Speed of string matching comparison operators

Tags: r, pattern-matching

I got curious about the speed of string comparison in R, when's the right time to use `!=` vs `==` and was wondering how much shortcutting they do.

If I have a vector with two levels, one which occurs frequently, and another which is rare, (trying to multiply my desired effect).

```
x <- sample(c('ALICE', 'HAL90000000000'), replace = TRUE, 1000, prob = c(0.05,0.95))
```

I would assume (if there is shortcutting) that the operation

`x != 'ALICE'`

would be considerably faster than:

`x == 'HAL90000000000'`

since to check equality in the latter case, I would assume I need to check every character, while the former would be invalidated by either the first or last character (depending on which side the algorithm checks)

but when I benchmark, it either does not seem to be the case (it was inconclusive in repeated trials, though with a very slight bias toward the `==` operation being faster ?!), or this isn't a fair trial:

```
> microbenchmark(x != 'ALICE', x == 'HAL90000000000')
Unit: microseconds
                  expr   min     lq    mean median     uq    max neval
          x != "ALICE" 4.520 4.5505 4.61831 4.5775 4.6525  4.970   100
 x == "HAL90000000000" 3.766 3.8015 4.00386 3.8425 3.9200 13.766   100
```

Why is this?

EDIT:

I'm assuming it's because it's doing full string matching, but if so, is there a way to get R to optimize these ones? I don't get any gains from the obfuscation of the amount of time it takes to match long or short strings, no worries about passwords.

Comment: Now that I think of it, I'm not sure  what do you expect. If you do `x == 'HAL90000000000'` and `x` is a vector, then you are trying to compare the whole vector against `'HAL90000000000'` (because `==` is vectorized). So what is your desired output? If you assume that R brakes `ALICE` into separate characters (like Python) than you are wrong, they are compared on C level as whole objects.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I was expecting something along these lines: [security se link](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83660/simple-string-comparisons-not-secure-against-timing-attacks) . How does the C level test them as whole objects? based on the code you sent, it very much looks like it's testing the strings part by part. But if I'm reading that wrong, then `Seql` must be right? How do you test entire strings other than by breaking them up somehow? (I ask as I continue to franticly look for that answer elsewhere)

Comment: I've actually haven't looked into `Seql` source code and that link of yours is too long to read. If you find something interesting in the source code, I would love to see

Comment: A "character" vector consists of objects (`CHARSXP`s) that are not appoachable at the R level. Each of those is cached and testing for equality involves comparing their C pointers -- there is no string comparison taking place (at least for ASCII "character"s). E.g. see `.Internal(inspect(c("ALICE", "HAL90000000000", x[c(1, 2)])))`

Comment: @alexis_laz That makes sense, so essentially, the string is factored anyway, because it's not storing extra copies of the object in memory. So it just looks up their address. But how does it also assign that address to the object that I've just created? if I say `x == "ALICE"` How does R know that ALICE is already in memory somewhere? Or do variables move in together at the first sign of equality?

Comment: @Shape : Any soon-to-be-character "char array" is passed to the function `mkChar` which -roughly- either returns the CHARSXP of an already hashed/`CHARSXP`ed "char array" or creates a new CHARSXP. So, typing "ALICE" in R, the parsed `char *` is passed to `mkChar` which will -everytime- return the `CHARSXP` that corresponds to the "ALICE" `CHARSXP` which was created the first time this "char" was seen, if I understand what you're saying correctly.

Comment: @alexis_laz Yep, that makes sense. Thank you! do you want to post as answer?